# FSUSB42 Schematic Review

Tags: circuit-design, diodes, usb, analog, multiplexer

I am using [FSUSB42](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fsusb42-d.pdf) in my project.The maximum recommended supply voltage of this IC is 4.4V (Absolute max is 5.6).

In my board 5V supply rail is available.I know I can power the device with 5V supply and it
will work.But this can reduce the life of the IC.(Please correct me if I am wrong)

For avoiding this I put a [diode](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mmsd4148t1-d.pdf) (Vf,(Max) @ If 1 V @ 10 mA) in series with the VCC line of the IC.

May I know your comment's about the below circuit.

[image]

Suggestions for improvement are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chip consumes so little current, about 1 uA, that the voltage drop over the diode is quite small. Even for 100 uA the drop is about 0.35V.

So it won't really change anything, unless you add a load resistor to draw more current through diode. But a low quiescent current 3.3V LDO might be a better solution that consumes less current.

Comment: Okay. will add an LDO then.